# CSS -webkit fading in menu

Tags: html, css, menu, fade, submenu

So I'm currently trying to get my menu (which worked well before I added the sub-menus) to fade color when hovered. I can't really understand what the problem is but guessing that the webkit function (Again, which worked before and I haven't touched it) isn't really affecting the hover function.

**Find code here:**

jsfiddle.net/ChH4F

Comment: Please include a jsfiddle or the code so this question could help others in the future.

Comment: The code is included, check the pastebin links.

Comment: I understand but when those links are no longer around, the question becomes useless. Here is a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ChH4F/.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle, let me know if this is what you are trying to do and then i'll explain. http://jsfiddle.net/ChH4F/1/

Comment: I'm trying to make it fade, i'll give you an example here: 
elevkarenkatedral.se/axelochaxel2.html

It should hover like the menu does there.

Comment: Ahh, give me one second. You have no hover state on your links so thats the biggest problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition you had was fine but without a hover state on your `a` tags there is nothing to change.

This is what I added,

```
ul#navmenu li a:hover {
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

This is what I changed since you don't need `all`,

```
-webkit-transition: color 0.7s ease;
-moz-transition: color 0.7s ease;
-o-transition: color 0.7s ease;
-ms-transition: color 0.7s ease;
transition: color 0.7s ease;
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChH4F/2/).

[Revision 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ChH4F/3/) - fading sub-menu links of the same color

[Revision 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ChH4F/4/) - fading sub-menu links of a different color

*Drop-Down fading in without JS/jQuery*,

```
ul#navmenu li ul.sub-menu {
   position: absolute;
   top: 40px;
   left: 0;
   width: 165px;
   background-color:rgba(0, 13, 38, 0.9);
   text-align:left;
   color:black;
   opacity: 0; /* Used to make it fade */
   height: 0; /* Used to make it fade */
   overflow: hidden; /* Used to make it fade */
}
ul#navmenu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
   opacity: 1; /* Used to make it fade */
   height: auto; /* Used to make it fade */
   overflow: none; /* Used to make it fade */
}
```

Also don't forget to add the `css-transitions` to your main `ul`, `ul.sub-menu`.

[Fade-in-out Menu](http://jsfiddle.net/ChH4F/1/)

What you are forgetting to add,

```
ul#navmenu, ul#navmenu ul.sub-menu {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0;
   padding-top:px;
   list-style-type: none;
   list-style-image: none;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   transition: all 0.6s ease;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

You need the `transition: all 0.6s ease;` on the element that is changing or it will just show/hide.

Comment: I love you!

Couldn't really move on without this...
As we speak... Is it possible to get the submenu text to fade when hovered too? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Lol, sure you can! If you want it to fade the same color then look at revision 1 and for a different color look at revision 2.

Comment: ILY x2! Well this starts to look great.
Since you are here and seem to know a lot (really, THANKS!), I've only have one, though, question left...
I want the drop down menu to fade in, can i do it only by using CSS or do i have to use javascript for that?
Thank you!

Comment: ILY x3? Refer to my edit on the answer. I also added a fiddle so you can see how it looks.

Comment: ILY x3 yes!
But i can't really get it to work though...
I've kinda just copied all the changes you did and added them, but it won't fade in. Actually nothing changes at all...
EDIT:

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/K6dLG/

Comment: It is better to not copy but write it so you end up remembering it. You aren't adding the transition to your sub-menu. I'll add the bit you are forgetting.

Comment: Let me see what is going on it your new fiddle.

Comment: Okay you didn't remove the `display: none;` and `display: block` which doesn't ease, instead it will just show and hide. Here is the new fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/K6dLG/1/.

Comment: I can't thank you enough!
I'll be in touch with you when the website is up and running if you want to check it out!
FYI I started learning HTML about a month ago (which hopefully give you some understanding of my bad knowledge).
Take care!

Comment: No problem! I would be happy to look the website over once it is done and you are doing very well for how little experience you have. Just email me the link when ever it is done and I'll let you know what I think. Best of luck in your coding!